# Pre-requisites itself requires a pre-requisite

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have created a windows form application and its set up in Visual studio set up project. I configure this set up project to have prereqisites like .Net framework 4.6.1, SQL localDB, Visual C++ libraries. Now the problem is when someone tries to install this Set up and it installs prerequisite like .netfx 4.6.1 it fails due to missing KB2919355 update. So this is i think pre requiste for a pre requisite, how should i set this now.

Comment: You can provide the `prerequisites` with the application itself by setting the `installation location` of the prerequisite to take the prerequisite from the application folder.

Comment: It is not about pre requisite it is about pre requisite for a pre requisite how would i know if some update say KB2919355 is installed or not or infact it is an update for windows 8.1 what if the client os is windows 7 or 10

Comment: I am just saying, i want my client to install .net framework 4.6.1 for be able to run my app. But for this framework itself he must have windows update KB2919355 (for windows 8), how am i as a developer suppose to know which OS my client is using and even if i did how i assume which update he is missing or not

Comment: OK, the first thing is that one can not take an assumption that what the client might or might not have installed in his system (_even though you can make that as your min requirements_) to run your application. The best as what we can do is provide him with all the tools necessary to run the application only. So, you are not liable for anything else other than your application if they do not have it simply tell them to install that.